# Assigning Value to Pointer Leads to Hard Fault

Tags: c, pointers, atmelstudio

I have narrowed the issue of a larger bug to something seemingly simple.

```
uint8_t *vald;
*vald=46;
```

This couplet of code leads to a hard fault on my platform (Atmel Studio, GCC)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have not allocated memory.

Comment: You are not "Assigning Value to Pointer". You are trying to assign a value to the `uint8_t` location your pointer is supposedly *pointing to*. But it isn't really pointing anywhere. The pointer is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vald is uninitialized, which means it's either zero or undefined depending on whether your compiler clears the stack frame for local variables.  Writing to address zero is always an error, and writing to an undefined address is almost always an error.

```
*((uint8_t*)0) = 46;
```